# Can't create component as it has dependencies to be satisfied in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I am getting an error while running a test. How do I solve this?

```
public class TestAppService : TestAppServiceBase, ITestAppService
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;
    public TestAppService(ITestRepository testRepository)
    {
        _testRepository = testRepository;
    }
}

public class TestAppService_Test : TestAppServiceTestBase
{
    private readonly ITestAppService _testAppService;
    public TestAppService_Test()
    {
        _testAppService = Resolve<ITestAppService>();
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
public class TestRepository : TestRepositoryBase<Test, int>, ITestRepository
{
    private readonly IActiveTransactionProvider _transactionProvider;
    public TestRepository(IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }

    public TestRepository(IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider,
        IActiveTransactionProvider transactionProvider, IObjectMapper objectMapper)
    : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
        _transactionProvider = transactionProvider;
        ObjectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
}

public interface ITestRepository : IRepository<Test, int>
{
}

public class TestRepositoryBase<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> : EfCoreRepositoryBase<TestDbContext, TEntity, TPrimaryKey>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    public IObjectMapper ObjectMapper;
    public TestRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Base class for custom repositories of the application.
/// This is a shortcut of <see cref="TestRepositoryBase{TEntity,TPrimaryKey}"/> for <see cref="int"/> primary key.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity type</typeparam>
public class TestRepositoryBase<TEntity> : TestRepositoryBase<TEntity, int>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
{
    public TestRepositoryBase(IDbContextProvider<TestDbContext> dbContextProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Test Name:

ABC.XYZ.Tests.PQR.TestAppService_Test.Should_Create_Test_With_Valid_Arguments
Test FullName:  ABC.XYZ.Tests.PQR.TestAppService_Test.Should_Create_Test_With_Valid_Arguments (20f54c54e5d9f077f4cb38b988ecb8e63e07d190)
Test Source:    C:\Users\viveknuna\source\repos\XYZ\aspnet-core\test\ABC.XYZ.Tests\PQR\TestAppService_test.cs : line 25
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.001

Result StackTrace:
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.AssertNotWaitingForDependency()
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve[T]()
   at ABC.XYZ.Tests.PQR.TestAppServiceTestBase..ctor() in C:\Users\viveknuna\source\repos\XYZ\aspnet-core\test\ABC.XYZ.Tests\PQR\TestAppServiceTestBase.cs:line 14
   at ABC.XYZ.Tests.PQR.TestAppService_Test..ctor() in C:\Users\viveknuna\source\repos\XYZ\aspnet-core\test\ABC.XYZ.Tests\PQR\TestAppService_test.cs:line 17
Result Message:
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException : Can't create component 'ABC.XYZ.Business.Services.PQR.TestAppService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'ABC.XYZ.Business.Services.PQR.TestAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'ABC.XYZ.Business.Repositories.Interfaces.ITestRepository' which was not registered.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException : Can't create component 'ABC.XYZ.Business.Services.PQR.TestAppService' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'ABC.XYZ.Business.Services.PQR.TestAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'ABC.XYZ.Business.Repositories.Interfaces.ITestRepository' which was not registered.

Add `DbSet<Test>` in your `DbContext`:

```
public class TestDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Add **AutoRepositoryTypes** to your `DbContext`:

```
[AutoRepositoryTypes(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(IRepository<,>),
    typeof(TestRepositoryBase<>),
    typeof(TestRepositoryBase<,>)
)]
public class TestDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    ...
}
```

---

> Target does not implement interface Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[Abp.Localization.Appl‌​icationLanguage, Abp.Zero.Common, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] Parameter name: target

Register `TestRepository`:

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IRepository<Test, int>>(() =>
{
    IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
        Component.For<IRepository<Test, int>, ITestRepository, TestRepository>()
            .ImplementedBy<TestRepository>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
    );
});
```

Explanation:

When you inject `ITestRepository`, it tries to instantiate `IRepository<Test, Int>` as defined. However, your `TestRepository` implements your custom `TestRepositoryBase<Test, int>`. Therefore, you need to replace `IRepository<Test, Int>` by registering your concrete class.

Reference:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entity-Framework-Core#replacing-default-repositories

---

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: TestDetailsDTO -> Test Abc.Xyz.Business.Dto.Tests.TestDetailsDTO -> Abc.Xyz.Business.Model.Taxes.Test

Add `[AutoMap(Test)]` attribute on `TestDetailsDTO`.

If that doesn't work, try to manually configure the mapping:

```
public class MyTestModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().UseStaticMapper = false;
        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<TestDetailsDTO, Test>();
            config.CreateMap<Test, TestDetailsDTO>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Should we replace the service in the EntityFrameworkCore module?

Comment: Yes, you can do it there.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by fixing my typo.  It seems the Windsor dependency injection follows a strict naming convention.

My interface was named ILeadStatusesAppService

And my concrete object was named LeadStatusAppService

As you can see I have a singular Status vs a plural Statuses.  After giving them both plural names (or singular) it worked.

Comment: life saver solution

Comment: Life saver! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the naming conventions that ABP recommended with no luck.  I tried refactoring the code again with no luck.  The weird part of this is that everything worked well in debug but as soon as I tried to publish or build as release the bug came back.

After several days of debugging and refactoring, I decided to compare the Release folder with Debug.  I noticed that Entity Framework Class Library in Release was different to Debug.  The dates were off.  Then it clicked, the reason why it couldn't create the Repository was that it wasn't actually available because EF Class Library was old and didn't have it in Release but did in Debug.  So I just cleaned everything again and made sure that EF was building a new DLL in Release and it worked.

It seems like an easy issue to resolve but it took some time to figure out :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue , turns out there was a circular dependency scenario . Both services were being injected each other's instances and were waiting to be resolved.

I corrected this and error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I realized that I just forgot to implement the application service interface that I've created, when I called it from the controller, I got this error